# Print element in list instantiated in constructor function from another function in python

Tags: python

I have a list instantiated in the constructor function of a class and I would like to print its content from another function but it doesn't print anything.

The Programm is very simple. It generates a list random integers until a specified limit is reached and hopefully it would print the content of that list.

Here's the code:

```
from random import randint


class NumGen:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.nums = []
        self.limit = limit

    def gen_rand_nums(self):
        for i in range(1, self.limit):
            self.nums.append(randint(1, 9))

    def display_nums(self):
        for i in self.nums:
            print(i)


print(NumGen(5).display_nums())
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't to call to `gen_rand_nums()`...

Comment: You need to call `gen_rand_nums()`, either from `__init__` or else manually after creating an instance.  Also, `display_nums()` prints the values in `nums` and implicitly returns `None`, so you don't want to pass the result to `print`, which will just print `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let suppose you have created an instance of the class. `self.num` is a list. But, `gen_rand_nums` is the function where you add elements to the list. But, if you didn't call that function, your list will remain empty.

Now, you are calling `display_nums` where you iterate over the elements of the **list**
: `self.nums`. But `self.nums` is empty because you did not add anything to the list. So, the list has no element for python to iterate over. So, all you get is a blank screen.

```
    def gen_rand_nums(self):
        for i in range(1, self.limit):
            self.nums.append(randint(1, 9))

    def display_nums(self):
        for i in self.nums:
            print(i)
```

The solution:

```
in1 = NumGen(5)
in1.gen_rand_nums()
in1.display_nums()
```

Now, when you call `gen_rand_nums`, it adds the elements to the list. And you will get the output

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `gen_rand_names()` and then print the values using `display_nums()`.

Also, you don't need to do `print(display_nums())` because `display_nums()` prints out all elements (*see the print statement inside it*).

```
from random import randint

class NumGen:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.nums = []
        self.limit = limit

    def gen_rand_nums(self):
        for i in range(1, self.limit):
            self.nums.append(randint(1, 9))

    def display_nums(self):
        for i in self.nums:
            print(i)


# Create an object
x = NumGen(5)

# Call to generate random numbers
x.gen_rand_nums()

# Print the generated random numbers
x.display_nums()
```

```
6
7
4
2
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `NumGen.gen_rand_nums()` before `NumGen.display_nums()` to generate list.

```
from random import randint


class NumGen:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.nums = []
        self.limit = limit

    def gen_rand_nums(self):
        for i in range(1, self.limit):
            self.nums.append(randint(1, 9))

    def display_nums(self):
        for i in self.nums:
            print(i)

num_gen = NumGen(5)
num_gen.gen_rand_nums()
print(num_gen.display_nums())
```